# My mouse cursor is self-clicking and flickering

Tags: windows-7, mouse, anti-virus, dism, mouse-click

My mouse cursor is behaving like mad, it's continuously self-clicking. Option of left-click appear without me clicking it and it selects on of the option from the list. Especially while browsing it automatically left-click and selects inspects elements and developers tools opens without me doing anything and flickering that is mouse cursor keeps appearing and disappearing, its been happening for last two months and its making me mad. I have tried everything from changing mouse to updating drivers to removing unnecessary programs which made it work for some days than it restarted.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you update the Mouse drivers?  Did you try a different Mouse?

Comment: yes @john i have done both

Comment: Boot with a bootable USB Key (Linux OS or Windows 10 ISO) and see if the mouse flickers with a bootable OS. Windows 7 is long gone so if it is your Windows system, time to upgrade.

Comment: Yes I have window 7